# SQL Check for Duplicate Records with Two Keys

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to combine these two statements into a single query?

There are two columns (a_id and b_id) against which the other 2 columns need to be unqiue.

```
SELECT * FROM cases WHERE a_id=:a_id AND case_form=:case_form AND case_type=:case_type

SELECT * FROM cases WHERE b_id=:b_id AND case_form=:case_form AND case_type=:case_type
```

..if any results returned alert user to duplicate case

Comment: Use an OR statement or a UNION?  But perhaps I'm not understanding could you post some sample data w/ expected results?  So... do you want to return all occurrences where case_form and case_type are duplicated in a_id and B_Id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two quick approaches:

```
SELECT * FROM cases WHERE a_id=:a_id AND case_form=:case_form AND case_type=:case_type
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM cases WHERE b_id=:b_id AND case_form=:case_form AND case_type=:case_type
```

or (no pun intended!)

```
SELECT * FROM cases 
WHERE (a_id=:a_id AND case_form=:case_form AND case_type=:case_type) 
   OR (b_id=:b_id AND case_form=:case_form AND case_type=:case_type)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can union

```
SELECT * FROM cases WHERE a_id=:a_id AND case_form=:case_form AND case_type=:case_type
UNION  ALL 
SELECT * FROM cases WHERE b_id=:b_id AND case_form=:case_form AND case_type=:case_type
```

or you can use OR

```
SELECT * FROM cases 
WHERE  ( a_id=:a_id  OR  b_id=:b_id ) 
AND case_form=:case_form AND case_type=:case_type
```

Comment: This is actually better as it simplifies the where clause on the or example; though the union should be a union all I think so you don't take the distinct performance hit.

Comment: @xQbert   answer  undeleted  .. thanks  .. (i have removed .. becase was a weird  situation  .. and i was thinking to the why  .) .. upvote for the courtesy

Comment: @scaaisEdge your welcome!  (Credit given where credit due)

Comment: @xQbert  Thanks, courtesy and loyalty do not seem widespread in SO, so when I meet right people makes me very happy

Comment: We should all aim to do better; I know we can, I know I can: and so I choose to to better where I can!